# How to get the $key from a multidimentional array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

Below is a simple array that I created:

```
$colors = array(

"parent1" =>array(
    "item1"=>"red", 
    "item2"=>"green", 
    "item3"=>"blue", 
    "item4"=>"yellow"   
),

"parent2" =>array(
    "item1"=>"red", 
    "item2"=>"green", 
    "item3"=>"blue", 
    "item4"=>"yellow"   
)   

);
```

What I need to get is the key of my level 1 arrays which are string "parent1" and "parent2".

Currently I'm using foreach with while loop to get the key

```
foreach ($colors as $valuep) {
    while (list($key, $value) = each($colors)) {
        echo "$key<br />";
    }
}
```

but I'm only able to get the "parent2" string from using the above method and not "parent1".

Answer (score 1):

You're so close.

```
foreah($colors as $key => $val)
{
   echo $key . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the key like so:

```
foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print out the keys:

```
foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . '<br />';
}
```

You can also get all of the keys from an array by using the `array_keys()` method, for example:

```
$keys = array_keys($colors);

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key . '<br />';
}
```